# How do I generate a pfx file from PEM?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a bunch of .Pem files.

One is (as far as I can tell) the CACert

mycacert.pem

the other is the certificate

mycert.pem

and finally what I am led to believe is the key file which is confusingly called the same as the certificate (but for this example I will call it something different)

key.pem

How do I form a PFX file from these?

I have tried to run the following command

```
openssl pkey -in C:\Temp\key.pem -out C:\Temp\my.key
```

however I get the following error

> unable to load key 2147581984:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no
> start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

If I open the file in notepad I see the following

-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
many characters
-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

Basically I just need to create a pfx from the files I have but I seem to need a *.key file, a *.crt file and another *.crt file for the CACert, non of which I have.

One more thing to note. The two certificate pem files contain multiple certificates in each.

Comment: pfx is just an alias for p12 = PKCS#12. So you should use `openssl pkcs12 ...` to create one.

Comment: But for that, I need a *.key file, a *.crt and a CA *.crt. I only have a bunch of PEM files...

Comment: PEM files are just base64 encoded files with a different extension. PEM files con contains key files, certificates and so on.

Comment: So is the -----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- header correct for a key file? I changed it to -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and I got a bunch of very different errors when using openssl rsa to check the keyfile.

Comment: Do not change the header, a CERTIFICATE REQUEST is a "Certificate Signing Request (CSR)" in PEM format (you have to send that to your Ca so it will get signed, but you already should have a file containing the private key). A PEM key has a header with PRIVATE KEY or similar. I am sorry but your question is incomplete: You don't tell us what you want to do what steps you have already performed. In that state the question can not be answered.

Comment: Sorry, I have just been given a bunch of files and need to make a soap request using the certificates. I seem to need the private key but was told that the key.pem file was what I needed. It seems that this is not actually the private key file. Basically I have installed the certificates but still get handshake errors when making the soap request. I am clearly missing something.

Comment: I have opened a new question regarding the root problem I have. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

The command you are looking for is:

`openssl pkcs12 -export -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -out pkcs12.pfx -certfile cacert.pem`

Where `cert.pem` is your certificate, `key.pem` is the private key, `cacert.pem` is the CA certificate and `pkcs12.pfx` is the pkcs12 file that will be created.

The command may asks for a password to decrypt the private key and will ask for a new password to encrypt the private key inside the pkcs12.

You can find the `openssl pkcs12` command documentation, [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-pkcs12.html#:%7E:text=The%20pkcs12%20command%20allows%20PKCS,Netscape%2C%20MSIE%20and%20MS%20Outlook.).