# How do I correctly install certificates to make soap request on windows 10

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I need to make a request to a soap service and it is protected with certificates.

I have installed the certificates as far as I am able to tell. However the soap request fails with handshake errors.

I have a bunch of certificate files given to me but I have no idea which ones are which.

So I have as follows (names changed to protect information)

MyCertificationAuthority.pem
MyCert.pem
MyCert2.pem

then I have what looks to be the same things in a different format.

MyCertificationAuthority.p7b
MyCert.p7b

then I have a single file named MyCert.pem but is smaller in file size than the other one of the same name and contains simply

> -----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- a lot of characters
> -----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

I was told that this was the private key file, however if I check it using

```
openssl rsa
```

then it errors.

I have double clicked on the p7b files and installed the certificates in them using the default options and I have those certificates in the Certificate Management app in windows.

3 are in the Third Part Certification Authorities folder
1 ended up in the Other People folder (which I have also copied into the Trusted Root Certification Authorities Folder)
4 have ended up in the Intermediate Certification Authorities Folder

All were installed for local computer rather than current user.

Now I am led to believe I should have a private key file too. However I can not find where this could be.

What am I doing wrong? Where would I normally get the private key file from?

I would have thought the service side has the private key in order to verify that our certificate is valid?

MyCert.pem is as follows (with the actual data removed for privacy reasons)

> subject=CN=********************** issuer=CN=************************
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE----- subject=CN=**************** issuer=CN=*****************
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> subject=CN=********************** issuer=CN=***********************
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: As you never give us the header details from the PEM files (just like in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755436) I am sorry but we can not help you.

Comment: The header is -----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST----- a lot of characters -----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----. Or do you need the header from one of the certificate pem files?

Comment: Please post the headers of every PEM file you have! -> Edit your question and add it there.